# What's interface for?

Tags: .net, oop

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Interfaces: Why can't I seem to grasp them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122883/interfaces-why-cant-i-seem-to-grasp-them)
>   [What is an Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5742022/what-is-an-interface)

At this time, all I know about Interface is that it contains classes, ... like a namespace. What is its purpose? Why don't we just use Namespace?

Thank you.

Comment: No, an interface *doesn't* contain classes. It contains methods, properties etc.

Comment: An interface is a contract. It tell's you how a class must act.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> An interface contains only the
>   signatures of *methods*, *delegates* or
>   *events*. The implementation of the
>   methods is done in the class that
>   implements the interface,

Answer (score 0):

See this duplicate post:

[What is an Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5742022/what-is-an-interface/5742161#5742161)

> An interface is like a template design
>   for a class that contains no data or
>   implemetnation; only definitions for
>   methods, properties etc. These are
>   abstract and cannot be instantiated
>   but can be inherited from at which
>   point all specified methods etc must
>   be implemented by the concrete class
>   inheriting the interface.